# Parsing similar named parameters out of a URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, url, parameters

I'm taking a URL that looks like this:

some_site.com/full/path/page.aspx?**label[0]**=a_value&**label[1]**=b_value&**label[2]**=c_value

The indexed number is generated, so there's a dynamic number of these 'label[x]' values every time.

What would the simplest way of parsing these all into a String[] named 'Label' in ASP/C#.NET 4.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `NameValueCollection` instead of array of Strings.

```
NameValueCollection queryParameters = new NameValueCollection();
string[] querySegments = queryString.Split('&');
foreach(string segment in querySegments)
{
   string[] parts = segment.Split('=');
   if (parts.Length > 0)
   {
      string key = parts[0].Trim(new char[] { '?', ' ' });
      string val = parts[1].Trim();

      queryParameters.Add(key, val);
   }
}
```

To get the number of the label withing the square brackets, use `Regular Expressions`.

```
regxObj = new Regex(@"\[(.*?)\]");
```

Comment: Excellent! This works quite nicely with what I want it to do.  Yeah, I only chose String[] initially as an example of the memory type.  I've never used NameValueCollections before so it didn't come to mind.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about enumerating the entries in the Request.Querystring collection?

Comment: more a suggestion for Drew to try that a question. I didn't think this site was about spoon feeding people. More about helping able professionals find answer quickly.

Comment: @HamishSmith - thats what I thought , I got downvoted for a suggestion :(

Comment: @HamishSmith No to be the bad (not give any -1) but I just say, that why not be sure and just say "do that". The question looks like you are not sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by taking the substring from the index of '?' to the end, then split by '&'.

Then you can either loop through that list and split by '=' and take the second element, or the substring of each of those starting after the index of '='.

If you do want it as just and array of strings for some reason, this one line will *probably* work.

```
String[] labels = (from substring in s.Substring(s.IndexOf('?') + 1).Split('&') select substring.Substring(substring.IndexOf('=') + 1)).ToArray();
```

edit: Do note that this disregards what the actual labels are, as well as their numbers; if there's something other than named, numbered `label[n]` tags, those will be added as to the array as well.

Answer (score -1):

make a parameter called length

```
 some_site.com/full/path/page.aspx?length=4&label[0]=a_value&label[1]=b_value&label[2]=c_value...
```

then that will be easy to parse on the other side already knowing the length

if you know the length , then you know how  many times to iterate through a loop to read the values of querystring

-or-

don't have a variable amount of parametes , use one , and use any special character to seperate them, then split the value by the seperating char on the other side